# Controlling Quicktime with javascript

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I am controlling quicktime with javascript and am playing a midi file.

I cannot get any of the following events to register.

```
qt_begin
qt_load
qt_ended
```

Etc
Here is the userguide 
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTScripting_JavaScript/bQTScripting_JavaScri_Document/QuickTimeandJavaScri.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001526-CH001-SW3

And here is my very simple code.

```
  QT_WriteOBJECT('test2.mid', '180','160', '',

       'obj#id', 'movie1', 'emb#name', 'movie1', 'enablejavascript', 'true');

       window.onload = load;


       function doSomething(){
       window.alert("Working!");           }

       function load()
       {
        document.getElementById('movie1').addEventListener('qt_load',doSomething);
       }
```

Wondering if it does not work with Midi Files?Or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: how is "movie1" assigned? (Does it possibly need to be `document.getElementById('movie1').addEvent...` (also `addEventListener` isn't cross-browser, if that matters))

Comment: move1 is assigned is the QT_WriteOJECT I tried what you suggested no luck.

Comment: I got it working.Had the wrong id.

Comment: If you fixed it, could you post what you did to fix it as an answer to your own question? That way this question can be closed in a few days.